# Is this an acceptable and correct proof for conjugation(a^(-1)ba)^n = (a^(-1)b^(n)a)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, induction, formal-proofs

I am a math autodidact learning abstract algebra in high school. I have limited resources at my school, and only one busy teacher to help me out, so I thought I would ask for help here.

I use Gallian's book for the exercises, and I was asked to prove: $$(a^{-1}ba)^n = a^{-1}b^na$$ for $$n \in Z$$ (integers) and 
$$(a,b) \in G$$
Where G is a group. When
$$n = 0 $$ then $$ e = a^{-1}ea=e$$
So with this base case we have:

$$(a^{-1}ba)^n(a^{-1}ba)=(a^{-1}b^na)(a^{-1}ba) =(a^{-1}b^n)(e)(ba)=a^{-1}b^{n+1}a$$
And for negative integers where $n \in Z+$
$$(a^{-1}ba)^{-n} = ((a^{-1}ba)^n)^{-1} = (a^{-1}b^na)^{-1} = 
(a^{-1}b^{-n}a)$$

Is this correct? My instructor has really been bagging on my proofs and I don't want to ask him yet.

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Comment: It's okay for Z because Z is abelian.  But it isn't okay for G in general.

Comment: Oh, wait.  You were doing a proof by induction.  Then..... I'm not comfortable with assuming b^0=e and that that'll make it true for b^n in general.  (All horses are the same color).  I'd do base case n=1.  Which should be no problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely not okay with n=0.  But if n=1 you have it just as easily.

Comment: @fleablood: There’s no problem with the induction step at $n=0$; write it out with $n$ replaced by $0$, and you’ll see that each step in the chain of equalities is fine. This isn’t analogous to *All horses are the same color*.

Comment: Maybe. but it makes me very uneasy to pop *anything* into existence.    I didn't mean to imply that this was an all horses are the same color but that all horses are the same color is a trap we should make a conscious effort to avoid.

Comment: Is there another way I should have wrote this? Obviously some people have problems with induction.